# How to make my gatsby link work properly in netlify?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, routelink

I am trying to route between pages in gatsby. It works in local host but sadly not in netlify. 
The route link is My-site.com/about/ It doesn't work in netlify but when I reload the page the route become My-site.com/About/ and the page content shows.

**In my index.js**

```
function Home = () => {
  return (
       <Link to="/about/"> About Page </Link>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

**In About.js**

```
function About = () => {
  return (
      <h2> This is About page </h2>
  );
};
export default About
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `About.js` file should be named `about.js` (lowercased). This is because with Gatsby, components under `src/pages` become pages automatically with paths based on their filename.

You can check [Pages and Layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/recipes/pages-layouts) documentation for further information.